# Delay method invocation

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following code:

```
public void onEnter() {

   Observable<GObject> obs = context.update(activeG);

   obs.subscribe((gObj) -> {

        //TODO: add delay of 3 sec.
        activeG.publishNewG();

        activeG.nextState(GType.RUNNING);
    });
}
```

My question is, How can I put a delay of 3 seconds so

```
activeG.publishNewG()
```

is called, then delay of 3 seconds, and then a call to

```
activeGame.nextState(GameStateType.RUNNING);
```

'publishNewG' returns void.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason for the delay? It seems like you're waiting for something to initialize in which case you should use events instead of waiting a certain amount of time since you can never be certain that 3 seconds is always enough.

Comment: Basically you're right, 3 seconds is something arbitrary...but this code is for testing so I just wanna do it like that.

Comment: Is `activeG` of a type that you've implemented - can you make it extend Observable?

Comment: Yes, I can extends Observable - but what good it would make me?

Comment: You can make it emit an event either when `publishNewG()` starts execution or when it finishes and then subscribe to `activeG.delay(3, TimeUnit.seconds())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put a 3 second delay between publishNewG and nextState. You can use `doOnNext` to inject activity at certain points in the sequence, for example, before and after a 3 second delay:

```
Observable.just(1)
.doOnNext(e -> System.out.println("Action before"))
.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.doOnNext(e -> System.out.println("Action after"))
.toBlocking().first();
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot, except that it uses 'toBlocking' which I cannot that since my server is asynchronous and cannot block the main thread. is there a way to tweak it and bypass the call to 'toBlocking' ?

Comment: Yes, I put it there so the example, when placed in a simple program's main method, won't exit prematurely.

Comment: if replacing .toBlocking with a simple call to 'subscribe' it doesn't work :-(

Comment: How did you try my example? Does it print "Action before" at least?

Comment: Fresh update: it does work with .subscribe() instead of .toBlocking(), I  didn't test it right!!

Comment: I choose your solution because it's the cleanest I could get and uses RxJava. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You would typically accomplish this using a scheduler of some sort. Java has [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that does this for you.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public MyClass() {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    public void onEnter() {

        Observable<GObject> obs = context.update(activeG);

        obs.subscribe((gObj) -> {

            activeG.publishNewG();
            // Run in 3 seconds
            scheduler.schedule(() -> {
                activeG.nextState(GType.RUNNING);
            }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: From what I can understand of the RxJava docs this is how you would do it with `delay`:

```
public void onEnter() {

    Observable<GObject> obs = context.update(activeG);
    // Observable that delays all events by 3 seconds
    Observable<GObject> delayed = obs.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // This will fire immediately when an event happens
    obs.subscribe((gObj) -> {
        activeG.publishNewG();
    });
    // This will fire 3 seconds after an event happens
    delayed.subscribe((gObj) ->  {
        activeG.nextState(GType.RUNNING);
    });
}
```

Comment: This will work, but RxJava has delay() methods that supposed to be doing this...my problem is how to use them... for example: if I could somehow wrap 'publishNewG()' in an Observable object then I could chain 'delay()' method.

Comment: I added an attempt at using `delay()` to accomplish it. Not sure if it will work though since I've never worked with RxJava. This will however fire 3 seconds after `publishNewG()` was called, not 3 seconds after it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add delay by using the `timer` operator.

For example:

```
    // simulated stream of events spread apart by 400ms
    Observable<Long> yourObservable = Observable.interval(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(3);

    yourObservable.flatMap(data -> {
        // add delay of 3 seconds
        return Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(i -> data);
    }).map(dataAfterDelay -> {
        // do whatever you want after 3 seconds
        System.out.println("got data " + dataAfterDelay + " after 3 seconds");
        return dataAfterDelay + " processed after delay";
    }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println); // toBlocking here just as example to block main thread
```

Comment: This approach will replace each source value with 0L. You'd want to map the timer value back to data.

Comment: You're right ... I missed that. I have added the .map(i -> data) code to the example.

Answer (score -3):

AFAIK you can use `Thread.sleep(3000)`

If not, something like this should do:

```
long start = new Date().getTime();
while(new Date().getTime() - start < 3000L){}
```

Comment: Edited and put in another solution using a while loop and `Date().getTime()`. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` should work as well.

Comment: But that's even worse. Not only are you seizing the main thread, you're also chewing up the CPU.